# Hide Unhide armature in viewport hotkey

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, armature

I'm making the switch from Maya to Blender, but one thing that I couldn't find is to assign a hotkey to hide and unhide an armature in the viewport. I don't like the visual clutter and as an animator I just want to make a pose and see it without all the controls of the rig.

So far I managed to find this, but now I need to assign it to a hotkey.

bpy.context.space_data.show_object_select_armature = False

bpy.context.space_data.show_object_select_armature = True

Cheers!

Edwin

Answer (score 0):

There is already a hot key assigned with Blender to show/hide any objects in the scene.

With Object/Objects selected press H or h on your keyboard to hide an object in the viewport
Press Alt + H or h on your keyboard to unhide object/objects in the viewport

Blender preferences for shortcut keys shows you this

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to speficially only hide the armature by a hotkey and not other objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to hide an armature:

- As proposed with hotkey `h` but that hides all selected objects
- In Outliner with symbol eye (hide in viewport)
- In Outliner with symbol monitor (disable in viewport, if not filtered) - same as Object Properties > Visibility > Show in Viewports
- In Armature Data Properties > Layers > select an empty layer
- Single bone in Bone Properties > Viewport Display > Hide
- View Object Types (3DView top right) > Armature > symbol eye
- Show Overlays (3DView top right) > Objects > Bones

There might be more I have forgotten, but all the ways also hide the transformation widgets of a selected bone, except the last one.

Most elements on the interface - not all - can be assigned a shortcut with the right mouse button.

Give this a try:

[image]

Key `F` suggested because not assigned in posemode (default) and near to rotation (R) and Grab (G) on keyboard. Now you can toggle with this shortcurt between hide and show bones, e.g. to select other bones. The transformation widgets are displayed as long as a bone is selected.

How do you get rid of it? RMB on checkbox bones in Viewport Overlays. There are other options if a shortcut was assigned to an UI element.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to go to viewport overlays and uncheck "bones" I was looking at the wrong menu.

[image: Bones]